# “on condition of his getting out of this then, come, and cutting it”

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, charles-dickens

What is the meaning of the highlighted part in this excerpt from *Bleak House*?

> “Policeman at last finds it necessary to support the law and seize a vocalist, who is released upon the flight of the rest *on condition of his getting out of this then, come, and cutting it*—a condition he immediately observes.”

If I had to guess, I would say that “getting out of this then” means “leaving immediately” and “cutting it” “stopping (what he is doing)”.

1. Is that correct?
2. What is the meaning or function of “come” here?

Comment: The whole passage is written in a very rapid clipped style. It's somewhat akin to the ""machine-gun fire" delivery of a sports commentator reporting on a tense finish to a race. In this case *getting out of this then, come, and cutting it* probably reflects the policeman saying something like *Get out of here then! Come on, cut along!* before letting the guy go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dickens is here including direct speech in the narrative without clues from the punctuation.
Notice in the previous paragraph he says without attribution, *Mr Krook warn't made away with.*

*get out of this then* is vernacular for escaping from a tricky situation.

> get out  [The Free Dictionary (Thesaurus "get out" vb)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/get+out)
>
> **4. leaving with difficulty**
>
> If you leave a building or room with difficulty, you say that you get out of it or get out.

*come* is the policeman's way of saying "Pay attention."

> (NTC's "Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs" lists 198 combinations); come on
>   (interj.) "be serious," [Online Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/come--on)

*cutting it* is vernacular for making a quick dash for freedom.

> cut and run (phrase of cut) 1. informal
>   *make a speedy departure from a difficult situation rather than deal with it*.  [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cut_and_run)